# Devportal apis total count doesn't match count in ui

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I got total apis count from publisher api `api/am/publisher/v2/apis` with curl command were 9. and count were 6.  The two counts don't match, is it an issue? In publisher ui, I promise it listed 6.
In devportal, it was different. The api `api/am/devportal/v2/apis` got total 9 , count 4, for there were some apis had more than one version.
How to get real totalcounts?

Thanks in advance.
Response from `api/am/publisher/v2/apis` like below.

```json
{
    "count": 6,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "df73b2e2-b64f-4341-864a-b115a4cc75ad",
            "name": "_s_test_api_1",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/api",
            "version": "v1.0.0",
            "provider": "admin",
            "type": "HTTP",
            "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
            "workflowStatus": null,
            "hasThumbnail": false,
            "securityScheme": [],
            "createdTime": "2022-05-19 03:38:56",
            "updatedTime": "2022-05-19 03:42:31"
        },
        {
            "id": "54967daf-1b8b-4f98-b800-68faa103b644",
            "name": "_s_test_api_1",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/api",
            "version": "v2.0.0",
            "provider": "admin",
            "type": "HTTP",
            "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
            "workflowStatus": null,
            "hasThumbnail": false,
            "securityScheme": [],
            "createdTime": "2022-05-19 03:42:31",
            "updatedTime": "2022-05-19 03:44:02"
        },
        {
            "id": "2fbeeb05-6562-42ad-abb8-b033512f606f",
            "name": "_sunlei_api_1",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/api1",
            "version": "v1.0.0",
            "provider": "admin",
            "type": "HTTP",
            "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
            "workflowStatus": null,
            "hasThumbnail": false,
            "securityScheme": [],
            "createdTime": "2022-05-19 04:04:10",
            "updatedTime": "2022-05-19 04:16:41"
        },
        {
            "id": "72622686-b4a5-47b3-8057-2d1f9bebd701",
            "name": "_sunlei_api_1",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/api1",
            "version": "v2.0.0",
            "provider": "admin",
            "type": "HTTP",
            "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
            "workflowStatus": null,
            "hasThumbnail": false,
            "securityScheme": [],
            "createdTime": "2022-05-19 04:16:41",
            "updatedTime": "2022-05-19 04:17:45"
        },
        {
            "id": "397b0ab6-057f-46ce-b074-95d35d2c3d45",
            "name": "士大夫",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/aaa1",
            "version": "v1",
            "provider": "admin",
            "type": "HTTP",
            "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
            "workflowStatus": null,
            "hasThumbnail": false,
            "securityScheme": [],
            "createdTime": "2022-05-20 04:16:10",
            "updatedTime": "2022-05-20 04:16:10"
        },
        {
            "id": "41381790-43f0-42fd-98d5-f1fe6a5ae2df",
            "name": "阿斯蒂芬",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/ttt111",
            "version": "v1",
            "provider": "admin",
            "type": "HTTP",
            "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
            "workflowStatus": null,
            "hasThumbnail": false,
            "securityScheme": [],
            "createdTime": "2022-05-20 04:15:53",
            "updatedTime": "2022-05-20 04:15:55"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 25,
        "total": 9,
        "next": "",
        "previous": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the API Manager version you are using? And can you share how many APIs are visible to you from Publisher portal? as well as from the Store/Devportal?

Comment: The version was wso2apim-4.0.0.     There were 6 apis visible to me from publisher portal, and 4 visible to me from devportal